# Scala: returning results from a case match

Tags: scala

I am attempting to write a helper class for querying my database. It looks something like this:

```
object Injury {
  def logger =  LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass)

    def find(teamId: Int = 0) {
        logger.info("teamId in find(): " + teamId)
        teamId match {
            case 0 => findAll
            case n => findById(n)
        }
    }

  def findAll = {
    val results = InjuryDAO.findAll
    results.map(grater[Injury].asObject(_)).toList
  }

  def findById(teamId: Int) = {
    //
  }

}
```

Now in my controller, I can simply call `Injury.find(someId)` and field the correct results. The problem is I'm not seeing any results, so I believe my Scala logic is incorrect somewhere. If I call `Injury.findAll` directly from my controller, all works great. in this case I'm passing a 0, verified it with the logger, but the `case 0` which should invoke findAll isn't being triggered properly. Obvious error here?

Comment: Are you simply missing an equals sign before the body of the `findById` method? That would have it returning `Unit`.

Comment: Sorry, the equals sign is there.. that's a typo. Updated.

Comment: Then what is the return type of `findById`, and does it match the return type of `findAll`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def find(teamId: Int = 0) {
```

`=` is missing, explaining why your method doesn't return anything (`Unit`).

Should be:

```
def find(teamId: Int = 0) = {
```

Comment: That isn't the problem unfortunately. If you look at comments in the original question, I noted that was simply a typo in my paste into here.

Comment: Comment above deals with the `findById` method, not the one I'm talking about. Looking at what you just post, you really missed the equals on the top-level `find` method. `find` is not a command, it's a query.

Comment: You can also try explicitly labeling your return types for ALL your functions.  That usually sheds light when you compile. e.g. def find(teamId: Int = 0): Int = {...}

Comment: Mik is right - that's embarrassing. I did leave it out from `find()`. I'm surprised that there was no compile error for this?

Comment: Try to precise all your method return types explicitly. You will see that this time, the compiler will notice some incoherence since it will have more info about the intention of your code.